# RHEL: Get rpm info as XML

Tags: xml, redhat, rpm

I need to retrieve the info of an installed RPM (*rpm -q "systemd" -i*) in XML format. According to the manual, it should be possible using --qf and -i, but I can't find the way to do it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rpm -qa --xml
```

This seems to work at least in CentOS 7. Man page about rpm commands query format is misleading IMO.

**EDIT:**

If the above is not sufficient, then you probably need to construct the xml yourself with the queryformat. Like this:

```
rpm -q systemd --qf "<name>%{NAME}</name><version>%{version}</version>\n"
```

You can check available tags with --querytags:

```
rpm --querytags
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, the solution you propose does not return the info I was looking for, but all the information about the rpm, including all files that are contained in it, which is way too much. But I agree with you... the documentation is a bit confusing...

Comment: Very useful. This solves my problem :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: please mark this as ´correct´ if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are more precise ways to construct XML than using using --queryformat.

First of all, --xml is simply a convenient wrapper for (see /usr/lib/rpm/rpmpopt)

```
rpm     alias --xml --qf '[%{*:xml}\n]' \
    --POPTdesc=$"list metadata in xml"
```

The point is that you can replace the '*' with any tag name you wish.

So similar to your XML sample, you can use quertformat's like

```
$ rpm -q --qf '%{NAME:xml}\n' bash
<string>bash</string>
```

Of course if you wish alternative markup to what is implemented in RPM you will have to script your own XML templates.